# Particle acceleration - why are colliders seemingly so limited?

Tags: energy, experimental-physics, accelerator-physics, particle-accelerators, theory-of-everything

I imagine this has been asked before but I am wondering why particle accelerators are so limited.

<s>- Why do they have to be big circles? Is there no other technique of accelerating charged particles?</s>

- Why does it take so much energy to accelerate a particle packet to merely 20kJ?

It seems a shame there is no method to accelerate particles to an arbitrary energy (that we have available) over a short distance  - **are they ruled out theoretically or has nobody figured it out yet**? We can do so much better than the momentum of a mosquito towards figuring out our TOEs!

Comment: The LHC beam has the _momentum_ of a mosquito, and it has roughly the _energy_ of a medium-size train (700MJ). Remember momentum and kinetic energy are not the same thing. However the entire beam is made of 35640 "bunches", which is maybe what you're talking about with your "particle packets," in which case each packet has 20 kJ... still A LOT more than a mosquito.

Comment: @AXensen thanks for clarifying, I will top up the question

Comment: You seem to be asking for a starter-course on accelerator physics. But this site is not intended for that. First inform yourself by widely available sources and then ask something more specific. Among the issues here are electrical breakdown which limits electric field strengths, and emission of radiation by accelerating charged particles which reduces their energy and momentum.

Comment: SLAC was a straight line accelerator 2 miles (3.2km) long.

Comment: @AndrewSteane thank you. I agree. I have amended the question to something short and simple and will be satisfied with a brief answer to that. Thanks for your feedback

Comment: If you have general questions about particle accelerator design, Don Lincoln of FermiLab made a series of videos. See [Videos by Don Lincoln](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLCfRa7MXBEsoJuAM8s6D8oKDPyBepBosS). In particular, see 48 - 53.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shuffle your shoes along a carpet on a dry day: you might build up 10 kilovolts of potential. Now bring your hand near a metallic object: a spark jumps. You've just accelerated electrons! You've accelerated a few quadrillion electrons to an energy of a few electron volts apiece. However, you haven't even come close to the 10 keV you might think you can get from 10 kV. You certainly haven't accelerated a few electrons to the PeV level that the energy released would seem to allow.

And this is the problem: it's easy to obtain lots of energy by subatomic standards, but it's difficult to concentrate that energy on a subatomic scale. Particle accelerators are elaborate machines that manage to do this without wasting too much energy on sparks and other loss mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks, that was enlightening. In your estimation, are there any promising avenues of achieving more efficient energy transfer on the subatomic scale left to explore, or are we really only taking the current mechanisms to further iterations?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_acceleration